# Amicable numbers program

Tags: shell, unix

Please help me the shell program below is giving me the following results

```
Solution.sh: line 7: 3..1184: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "..1184")
Solution.sh: line 10: 3..1210: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "..1210")
```

```
read a
read b
c=0
d=0
for i in 1 2 3..$a
do
if [[ $(( $a % i )) == 0 ]]
then
c=c+i
fi
done
for j in 1 2 3..$b
do
if [[ $(( $b % j )) == 0 ]]
then
d=d+i
fi
done
if [[ $a == $d && $b == $c ]]
then
echo "The pair is amicable"
else
echo "The pair is not amicable"
fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure `for i in 1 2 3..$a` is going to work properly. Try `for i in {1..$a}` instead?

Comment: A number of other issues, too. Start by running your script through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @r3mainer is correct  that won't work ....     BTW Where is the amicable numbers assignment being done - this is the third one in as many days ......  AND IIRC you have to throw away whatever is paired with one (because the NUMBER is not part of the answer - so that logic is wrong.

Comment: @Mr R An assessment is going on for testing skills in unix that's why you are seeing these questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
read -r a
read -r b
c=0
d=0

for ((i = 1 ; i < $a ; i++))
do
if [[ $(( a % i )) -eq 0 ]]
then
    c=$(( c + i ))
fi
done

for ((j = 1 ; j < $b ; j++))
do
if [[ $(( b % j )) -eq 0 ]] 
then
    d=$(( d + j ))
fi
done

if [[ $a == $d && $b == $c ]]
then
    echo "Pair is amicable"
else
    echo "Pair is not amicable"
fi
```